# using grep or awk to find files that contain both "a" and "b" that are on different lines

Tags: unix, awk, grep

Is there a way to use `grep` or `awk` to find text files that contain both e.g. "a" and "b" but in this case "a" and "b" are on different lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple `awk` solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN {acnt=0; bcnt=0;} /a/ {acnt++;} /b/ {bcnt++} END { if (acnt > 0 && bcnt > 0) print "Matches"; }' $FILE
```

A slightly simpler way is to just use `grep`, leveraging its return value as an indicator that the value was found:

```
grep -l a $FILE && grep -l b $FILE && echo "Both a and b found in $FILE"
```

You may want to redirect standard output, but the above should be simple and functional. You could wrap it in a loop if wanted:

```
files=""
for x in *; do
    grep -l a $x && grep -l b $x && files="$files $x" # assuming no spaces
done
# now you can iterate over $files
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/a/{f=1}/b/{g=1}END{if(f && g) print "matches"}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to cobble something together with some nasty shell which parsed the output of grepping for "a" and used that to build up a list of files to grep for "b", but if it were me I'd put together a short perl script.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
grep -lP '(?m)(a.*(.*\n)*.*b)|(b.*(.*\n)*.*a)' *
```